# How to access variable of other perl program in my perl program

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I have three different Perl programs. I want to access the value of a variable present in the first program in the other two Perl programs.

My first Perl program look like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";

use CGI;
use Cwd;
use utf8;
$q=new CGI;
$a=$q->param('file');
#chomp($a);
my $ftpname="$a";
```

This program takes value from a text of HTML program. I need the value of the $ftpname variable in my other to Perl programs. How can I do that?

Comment: What other two Perl programs? How are they related to this one? (Why aren't you using `strict` and `warnings`?)

Comment: This is the wrong way to do things; Perl has modules, modules typically create a namespace for themselves by using the `package` statement.  And scripts call the use of these modules with `use` or `require`, at which point the module's package variables become available.  Accessing a module's package variables is still bad form in most cases, but it's better than using `do filename.pl` on some library that doesn't create its own namespace.

Comment: @Quentin I don't think it's relevant what the other programs look like, he's asking how to read the value of a variable defined in one program from another program.

Comment: @user3395299 I don't think you can intercommunicate between programs directly unless one calls the other. For example, if this program returns the value of **$ftpname**, in the other program you can use this program as a function, and store its results in a variable. An alternative would be to store **$ftpname** in a temp file, and have the other program read that temp file.

Comment: @AdiInbar — Which makes the way they interact *very* relevant. Are they going to make HTTP requests to other CGI programs? Shell out? Parse the source code.

Answer (score 0):

There can be more than one way to solve your problem.

1. You can save the value of `$a` in a text file and then read that text file in your other two programs.
2. You can create a module that contains functions to act upon the value of `$a`. Then you can call the proper moduleName::functionName with `$a` as argument. A simple tutorial to get you started would be [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=102347).
3. If you want to share variables anyway, you can have a module that acts as some sort of header file with the variable declarations (using the `our` keyword and/or exporting), and then this module is `use`d in all of your other perl scripts and the variable is visible everywhere. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16472634/240901). For more help on variable scope, you may read this reference: [Coping with Scoping](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html)

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/228805). Please include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain how it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is ultimately that you need to use sessions to save state information from one page to the next.  [`CGI::Session::Tutorial`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session::Tutorial) is a good for an introduction to the concept and some of the early alternatives.

Below you will find two scripts that demonstrate this practice.  But first.

1. Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of each and every perl script you make.  This will make you a better coder and help you find errors quicker.  For more reasons check out: [`Why use strict and warnings?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)
2. Because you're using [`CGI`](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html), you should also use [`CGI::Carp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Carp).  Simply include the following line after your `use CGI;` statement: `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);`
3. Your problem is going to be solved by using [`CGI::Session`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session) to save state information between pages.  The below scripts save a variable in the first script that is used by the second.  You should be able to adapt this to your 3 script scenario.
4. It's good that you're outputting an http header first thing, but let `CGI` do that for you.  Normally, I'd say use `print $q->header();`.  That will output the same header as you were doing manually.  However, because we want `CGI::Session` to be able to set a cookie, I'll be demonstrating the use of `print $session->header();` instead.

This first script named `step1.pl` sets a random variable and saves it to the session.  Once it's set it provides a link to the next step.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI::Session;

my $q = CGI->new;
my $session = CGI::Session->new($q) or die CGI->Session->errstr;
print $session->header();

$session->save_param($q, ['dependentvar']);
#$session->load_param($q, ['dependentvar']); # Uncomment this if you want the text field initialized when returning to the form.

# Random Page View Count
my $count = 1 + ($session->param('count') // 0);
$session->param('count' => $count);

print qq{
<html>
<head><title>Step 1</title></head>
<body>
<h3>Step 1</h3>
<p>Goal: Set a random value that must be initialized before proceeding to step 2.</p>
<p>Number of Page views this session: $count</p>
<div><form method="POST">};

print $q->textfield("dependentvar");
print $q->submit("set");

print qq{</form></div>};

if ($q->param('dependentvar')) {
    print qq{<div>You have a value set, you can proceed to <a href="step2.pl">step 2</a></div>};
}

print qq{
</body>
</html>};
```

And the second script, `step2.pl`, which requires that the dependentvar is set before proceeding, and then lets the user perform some translations on the string.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI::Session;

my $q = CGI->new;
my $session = CGI::Session->new($q) or die CGI->Session->errstr;
print $session->header();

my $var = $session->param('dependentvar');

# Verify that our dependent variable was set in the previous step.
if (!$var) {
    print qq{
<html>
<head><title>Step 2</title></head>
<body>
<h3>Step 2</h3>
<p>You must set a value in <a href="step1.pl">step 1</a> before proceeding with step 2</p>
</body>
<html>};
    exit;
}

print qq{
<html>
<head><title>Step 2</title></head>
<body>
<h3>Step 2</h3>
<p>Goal: Take variable from <a href="step1.pl">Step 1</a> and perform some translations on it.</p>
<div><form method="POST">};

print q{<div>} . $q->checkbox('double') . q{</div>};
print q{<div>} . $q->checkbox('reverse') . q{</div>};
print q{<div>} . $q->checkbox('upper') . q{</div>};
print q{<div>} . $q->checkbox('lower') . q{</div>};
print q{<div>} . $q->checkbox('ucfirst') . q{</div>};
print q{<div>} . $q->checkbox('lcfirst') . q{</div>};

print q{<p>} . $q->submit("transform") . q{</p>};

print qq{</form></div>};

if ($q->param('transform')) {
    my $newvar = $var;
    $newvar x= 2 if $q->param('double');
    $newvar = reverse $newvar if $q->param('reverse');
    $newvar = uc $newvar if $q->param('upper');
    $newvar = lc $newvar if $q->param('lower');
    $newvar = ucfirst $newvar if $q->param('ucfirst');
    $newvar = lcfirst $newvar if $q->param('lcfirst');

    print qq{<div>$var -&gt; $newvar</div>};
}

print qq{
</body>
</html>};
```

This should serve as an introduction to the concept of sessions.  There are other methods to pass a variable from one web script to the next, but as was discussed in [`CGI::Session::Tutorial`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session::Tutorial) this methods are very fragile.  Finally, please read that entire tutorial before applying this solution to your code.