# shopping cart implementation using perl

Tags: perl, cookies, perl-module

I need to design a shopping cart using perl such that the user gets clear idea of the goods he choose to buy. I thought of saving data of those items in a cookie. But i wonder how to update an already existing cookie each time an item is added. Is there any better way to design a cart/checkout page. Is there any perl module which makes my work easier?

Here is the snippet i tried out for updating cookie of cart

```
$cooki = $q->cookie('CART'); #retrieve cookie CART if already exists into var $cooki
$val2 = $cooki;
$val1 = $picid;
$cooki=$q->cookie(-name=>'CART',
-value =>["$val1"," $val2"],
-expires=>'+5m',
-path=>'/');
print $q->header(-cookie=>$cooki);
```

retrieval:

```
$cooki = $q->cookie('CART');
```

But it stores only the current id of the pic selected like for ex '45%20' i.e. 45 with a space and not multiple values like '45 12 16' . Where could i go wrong?

Comment: I tried your code snippet and it works fine for me, please double check the values in the variables.

Comment: i couldn't get it. every time i add an item or call the script the value of the cookie is the id pertained only to that item.

Comment: Storing anything except session ID in cookie is rarely good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Cookies, instead use [`CGI::Session`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI%3a%3aSession).  For all the reasons why, you can read [`CGI::Session::Tutorial`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI%3a%3aSession%3a%3aTutorial).

I created a working examples of using sessions to transfer information from one form to another in this question: [`How to access variable of other perl program in my perl program`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22599385/1733163)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, because the return is an array:

```
@cooki = $q->cookie('CART');
```

Comment: the return is indeed an array. I modified it. But the retrieval displays for ex '25&0' i.e. the already existing cookie value is set to 0 or returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CGI::Cookie](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI%3a%3aCookie) and set cookies in anonymous array

```
 my $c = CGI::Cookie->new(-name    =>  'CART',
                          -value   =>  ['45','12','16'],
```

then fetch existing cookies by:

```
    %cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
    $cart = $cookies{'CART'}->value;
```