# Why doesn't CGI::Sessions work?

Tags: perl, redirect, cgi

I have two files, one is the login from which I get user credentials and I want to forward the user to another page if he passes authentication using CGI::Sessions. The problem is that I am missing something in the hello.pl file. I looked online for code examples but couldn't find any with two or more files. What should I put in my code in hello.pl in order to redirect using sessions so the variable username can be pulled out from hello.pl

login.pl:

```
 1 #!/usr/bin/perl -wT
  2  use strict;
  3 
  4 use CGI::Session;
  5 use CGI qw(:standard);
  6 
  7 my %names = map { $_ => 1 } param;
  8 my $open = "1234";
  9 
 10 sub windowLayout() {
 11           header,
 12           start_html("Input Form"),
 13           start_form,
 14           "Please enter your username:",
 15           textfield(-name=>'username',
 16                           -maxlength=>20),p,
 17           "Please enter your password:",
 18           password_field(-name=>'password',
 19                           -maxlength=>20),p,
 20           submit,hr
 21 }
 22 
 23 if ($names{username} and $names{password}) {
 24 
 25 my $cgi = new CGI;
 26 my $session = new CGI::Session(undef, $cgi, {Directory=>'/tmp'});
 27 
 28 my $cookie = $cgi->cookie(CGISESSID => $session->id);
 29 print $cgi->header(-cookie=>$cookie);
 30 
 31 my $username  = param("username");
 32 my $password  = param("password");
 33 
 34 $session->param('username', $username);
 35 $session->param('password', $password);
 36 
 37  if ($password ne $open) {
 38        print
 39         windowLayout(),
 40         end_form,
 41           p({-style=>'Color: red;'},
 42                  "Sorry wrong password!");
 43        print end_html;
 44   } else {
 45        print
 46           redirect("hello.pl");
 47   }
 48  }else {
 49     print
 50          windowLayout(),
 51          end_html;
 52  }
```

hello.pl

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -wT
  2 use strict;
  3 
  4 use CGI::Session;
  5 use CGI qw(:standard);
  6 
  7 #my $cgi = CGI->new;
  8 #my $usrname = $cgi->param("username");
  9 
 10 my $username = $session->param("username");
 11 
 12 print   
 13     header,
 14     start_html (-BGCOLOR=>'green'),
 15     "Hello, $usrname",p,
 16     "The time now is: ",
 17      scalar(localtime),
 18 #     h1({-style=>'Color: orange;'}, "$usrname you win \$1,000,000!");
 19     end_html;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking at the following question for an additional example on using [`CGI::Session`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session):

- [How to access variable of other perl program in my perl program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22599385/1733163)

However, your two scripts can be cleaned up to work at transferring the username from one to the other.

The biggest thing I would recommend is setting your `CGI` object and `CGI::Session` object first thing.  This is true of both of your scripts and any other cgi style scripts that you would create:

login.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI::Session;
use CGI qw(:standard);

my $open = "1234";

my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $session = CGI::Session->new( undef, $cgi, { Directory => '/tmp' } )
  or die CGI::Session->errstr;
my $username = $cgi->param('username') // '';
my $password = $cgi->param('password') // '';

# Process Form
my @errors;
if ( $cgi->request_method eq 'POST' ) {
    if ( !$username ) {
        push @errors, "No username specified.";
    }

    if ( !$password ) {
        push @errors, "No password specified.";
    }
    elsif ( $password ne $open ) {
        push @errors, "Sorry, wrong password.";
    }

    if ( !@errors ) {
        $session->param( username => $username );
        print $cgi->redirect("hello.pl");
        exit;
    }
}

print $session->header(),
  start_html("Input Form"),
  start_form,
  p(
    "Please enter your username:",
    textfield(
        -name      => 'username',
        -maxlength => 20
    )
  ),
  p(
    "Please enter your password:",
    textfield(
        -name      => 'password',
        -maxlength => 20
    )
  ),
  p(submit), hr,
  end_form,
  map( { p( { -style => 'Color: red;' }, $_ ) } @errors ),
  end_html();
```

hello.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI::Session;
use CGI qw(:standard);

my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $session = CGI::Session->new( undef, $cgi, { Directory => '/tmp' } )
  or die CGI::Session->errstr;

my $username = $session->param('username');

print header,
  start_html( -BGCOLOR => 'green' ),
  p("Hello, $username"), p( "The time now is: ", scalar(localtime) ),
  end_html;
```

Comment: You obviously know a lot about Web Programming and Perl, so I was wondering if you could give me some advise on which framework to use.  I saw the video entitled 'Why Perl.pm must die' I cannot rely on the validity of the points made there since it was made by a competitor to Perl.pm and I lack experience in Perl.pm. But the solution, as presented there, was Dancer framework. Here's the link to the video. [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tu6_3fZbWYw] What are you thoughts on the matter and which framework would you recommend?

Comment: One list of more modern alternatives can be found at [`CGI::Alternatives`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives).  I have a pretty strong affection for both [`Dancer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer) and [`Mojolicious`](https://metacpan.org/search?q=mojolicious), but practically anything is going to be more modern than `CGI`.  It works for an introduction, but no new websites should be coded in it.