# How do I get the name of the currently-running Perl script?

Tags: perl

I have a script

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';
use autodie ':default';
use mwe 'tmp';

tmp();
```

that calls a Perl module `mwe`

```
use feature 'say';
package mwe;
use Cwd 'getcwd';
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT = qw(tmp);

sub tmp {
    say 'written by ' . getcwd() . '/' . __FILE__;
}
1;
```

but when I run this script, the filename appears from the module:

```
con@V:~/Scripts$ perl mwe.pl
written by /home/con/Scripts//home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.34.0/lib/5.34.0/mwe.pm
```

I'm still new at writing modules, so criticism there is appreciated, if my minimal working example isn't well-written.

My question:
I'm aware that I could pass the file `/home/con/Scripts/mwe.pl` as a parameter to the subroutine `tmp`, but is there a way that I could get a subroutine like `tmp` to return the script filename instead automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```perl
use FindBin qw( $RealScript );
say $RealScript;
```

or

```perl
use Cwd qw( abs_path );
say abs_path($0);
```

---

Most of the time, people actually want the directory in which the script resides. For that, use

```perl
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
say $RealBin;
```

or

```perl
use Cwd qw( abs_path );
use File::Basename qw( dirname );
say dirname(abs_path($0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this in mwe.pm:

```
say 'written by ' . getcwd() . '/' . __FILE__;
```

Use:

```
say 'written by ' . getcwd() . '/' . $0;
```

Comment: This will often fail.

Comment: To be clear, this will fail if an absolute path is passed to `perl`, which is a common occurrence.

Comment: @ikegami at first I almost gave a response that passed the file path from the script to the module.

Answer (score -1):

Please investigate the following code snippet if it comply with your question.

A variable declared with `our $__SCRIPT__ = abs_path($0)` in main script which takes name of the script `$0` and adds absolute path.

This variable can be accessed from any module as `$main::__SCRIPT__`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Cwd 'abs_path';
use Test::Some;

our $__SCRIPT__ = abs_path($0);

my $args = {
              id  => '2000',
              str => 'Magic string'
           };

my $m = new Some($args);

$m->show();
```

Source code of module `Test::Some`

```
package Some;

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

sub new {
    my ($class, $arg) = @_;
    my $self = bless {
            id      => $arg->{id},
            str     => $arg->{str}
    }, $class;

    return $self;
}

sub show {
    my $self = shift;

    say 'PACKAGE:  ' . __PACKAGE__;
    say 'PKG_FILE: ' . __FILE__;
    say 'SCRIPT:   ' . $main::__SCRIPT__;
    say 'SELF_ID:  ' . $self->{id};
    say 'SELF_STR: ' . $self->{str};
}

1;
```

Sample of output

```
PACKAGE:  Some
PKG_FILE: /kunden/homepages/6/d807xxxxxx/htdocs/.perl/Test/Some.pm
SCRIPT:   /homepages/6/d807xxxxxx/htdocs/work/perl/examples/xmodule.pl
SELF_ID:  2000
SELF_STR: Magic string
```

Reference:
[abs_path](https://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd),
[Perl global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472187/perl-global-variables-available-in-all-included-scripts-and-modules)